# Can compass merge .css files?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to find out if Compass can merge .css files rather than using a third party tool to merge the .css files after Compass has compiled the .scss files. I have looked around the web and on here but nothing so far. I thought the config.rb may have an option for this but all I found is compress feature.

Anyone tried this or have a found a third party tool that works well with compass?

Comment: Have you look at this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688291/how-to-merge-css-files-with-sass-or-other-tool

Comment: @cram1010 yeah thanks, I read this before posting... I was hoping to merge .css via Compass but with the lack of answers or suggestions I may just go with a third party tool.

Comment: yeah, I think there is no way with compass :(

Comment: Concatenating .css files should be part of your deploy process

Comment: Alternatively you can do a production.scss with multiple @import directives towards your different .scss files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd wanted to do this same thing for quite some time. I finally settled on the following solution.

**Take the following structure (i.e. with your modules in a sub-folder of `sass`)**

> - project
>
>   - sass
>
>     - modules
>
>       - header.scss
>       - blog-posts.scss
>       - footer.scss
>       - something-else.scss
>     - main.scss
>   - stylesheets

**Update `main.scss` to contain:**

```
@import 'modules/header.scss';
@import 'modules/blog-posts.scss';
@import 'modules/footer.scss';
@import 'modules/something-else.scss';
```

**Run the following command (from the `project` folder) in order to build**

```
compass compile . sass/main.scss -s compressed
```

This just compiles `main.scss`, which inturn goes and imports each of your modules. Additionally the `compressed` style option minifies the output.

Comment: Great answer, I will be using this... thanks beardo!

Comment: omg so simple.
I'm so dumb sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

It's not compression, but you can exclude files from being copied to the output directory by prepending an underscore to their names. For example:

```
scss/
    _core.scss // will not be copied
    theme.scss  // @import 'core';
css/

compass compile
    create ../css/theme.css

css/
    theme.css
```