# Compass and sass: possible to auto-import all partials?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

In a compass/sass setup, ideally I would like to compile every .scss-file into one big `style.css`. Looking e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688291/how-to-merge-css-files-with-sass-or-other-tool), it seems my only option would be to make `_partials.scss` 
and `@import "these";` from one main file. This seems like double work, since every time I move around a .scss-file e.g. to a sub folder I have to update the referenced import-path.

My question is: is it possible with compass instead to just watch a folder and always compile all partials into one single target output file?

Comment: How would Sass know what order to include the files?  Order impacts the cascade, and mixins have to be defined before they can be used.

Comment: @cimmanon If he doesn't mind they being imported alphabetically, he could use the [Sass Globbing Plugin](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing).

Comment: Good point, @cimmanon, that obviously this could mess up cascading that relies on rule order. Most cases, though, ensuring that mixins are loaded first (e.g. through prefixing files with double-underscore or the like) would suffice. Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [Sass Globbing Plugin](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing).

This way you can import an entire folder:

```
@import "library/partials/*"
```

The partials will be sorted alphabetically before being imported.

Comment: it seems it has problems with windows, and also it's not full compatible with GULP right now (see issues page)