# Conditionally import partials - Compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to conditionally import a sass partial if it exists to override a set of default styling variables.  I'm looking for a means to accomplish the following, given that @import directives cannot be nested:

```
 @if 'partials/theme'{
   @import 'partials/theme';
 }
```

Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins, so what is the proper approach for referencing a partial that may or may not exist?

Comment: I can add an empty placeholder file to accomplish this, but would prefer something a bit more tidy.

Comment: Here you are! ^_^

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954330/compass-and-sass-possible-to-auto-import-all-partials

<!-- yay -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In retrospect, the best solution you would probably use JavaScript to conditionally load in theme assets or modules.

Comment: Yep, this is how I ended up working around it (via yepnope:http://yepnopejs.com/). I probably should have left a comment to close the loop after I got it working. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It is not good solution, we need a way in sass.. maybe using mixin...

Comment: For a mixin solution see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13879344/1446845

Answer (score 5):

You can't explicitly use the import directive inside control directives.

"It’s not possible to nest @import within mixins or control directives." - [Sass Reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import)

```
 error sass/screen.scss (Line 9: Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.)
```

If you really need this there are sort of ways of getting around it with the `@content` directive. But it really depends on what your task really boils down to.

One example which would produce multiple .css file outputs for each theme, you might approach like this:

**_config.scss**

```
$theme-a: false !default;

// add content only to the IE stylesheet
@mixin theme-a {
  @if ($theme-a == true) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

**_module.scss**

```
.widget {
  @include theme-a {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

**all.theme-a.scss**

```
@charset "UTF-8";

$theme-a: true;

@import "all";
```

In another case, to produce multiple theme options in a single .css output you might have to rely on complex looping like this:

```
//
// Category theme settings
// ------------------------------------------
// store config in an associated array so we can loop through
// and correctly assign values
//
// Use this like this:
// Note - The repeated loop cannot be abstracted to a mixin becuase
// sass wont yet allow us to pass arguments to the @content directive
// Place the loop inside a selector
//
//      .el {
//          @each $theme in $category-config {
//              $class: nth($theme, 1);
//              $color-prop: nth($theme, 2);
//
//              .#{$class} & {
//                  border: 1px solid $color-prop;
//              }
//          }
//      }
//

$category-config:
    'page-news-opinion' $color-quaternary,
    'page-advertising' #e54028,
    'page-newspaper-media' $color-secondary,
    'page-audience-insights' $color-tertiary,
;


$news-opinion-args: nth($category-config, 1);
    $news-opinion-class: nth($news-opinion-args, 1);
    $news-opinion-color: nth($news-opinion-args, 2);

$advertising-args: nth($category-config, 2);
    $advertising-class: nth($advertising-args, 1);
    $advertising-color: nth($advertising-args, 2);

$news-media-args: nth($category-config, 3);
    $news-media-class: nth($news-media-args, 1);
    $news-media-color: nth($news-media-args, 2);

$audience-args: nth($category-config, 4);
    $audience-class: nth($audience-args, 1);
    $audience-color: nth($audience-args, 2);
```