# How to force SASS to merge external css files?

Tags: css, sass

How to force SASS to merge external css files?

```
//these two files will not merged
@import "js/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
@import "js/selectize/css/selectize.css";
//thess two files will be merged
@import "js/font-awesome/css/x.scss";
@import "js/selectize/css/y.scss";
```

I do not want to rename foo.css to foo.sass.

Comment: @kleinfreund `scss` files are OK. The problem is about `css` files.

Answer (score 0):

Without renaming or adding the partial "_" underscore in front of the filename it is not possible to do as you wish - as far as I know.

I came across this post: [How to merge .CSS files with Sass (or other tool)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688291/how-to-merge-css-files-with-sass-or-other-tool)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, what is the effect of using `_` ?

Comment: Generally, you have a main source file in which you include a "partial" its kindof like "including" but in sass it merges the files instead of just loading both individually (1 big file, 1 request). And you dont have to worry about the file-type it can be either sass, scss or css. You can specify a partial with that underscore in the filename. Then to import this file use: @import "mypartial"